# Why do edges not show up correctly in networkx drawing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am using the latest networkx on Python3 with Linux Mint 17. I am using the pcalg method (https://github.com/keiichishima/pcalg) to build directed acyclic graphs from data. I checked to be sure that the graph has edges using the number_of_edges() function.

My code looks like this:

```
skel_1, sep_1 = alg.estimate_skeleton(ci.ci_test_dis, Mat_1, 0.1)
dag_1 = alg.estimate_cpdag(skel_1, sep_1)
num_edge1 = dag_1.number_of_edges()
print(num_edge1)
nx.draw_networkx(dag_1, arrows=True, edge_color='b')
plt.savefig("Target1.png")
plt.close()
```

When I execute this code, the nodes show up, but not the edges. Is this because I did not include the pos parameter?

Comment: There's nothing obvious to me, so it would take a deeper dive into your code.  Can you provide a [mcve]?  I can't run this without `alg` and `ci`.  Can you also say how many nodes and edges are in your graph?  Perhaps also provide `Target1.png`.

Comment: Based on the printout that I got from the number_of_edges() function, the graph has four edges. This is not the correct amount based on the data, but that is separate issue. In the resulting picture, however, the graph is not shown to have any edges. In order to provide you with an executable example, you will need the pcalg method provided in the link, as well as the gsq modules by the same author. The latter of these has some notable errors that  had to correct in order to run it. If you reply to me in regular answer form, I can provide a picture.

Comment: how many nodes?  I suspect that what's happening is just that the number of nodes is large, so the nodes are plotted close together, and the edges are there, but simply not seen.

Comment: There are 24 nodes altogether. They all show up correctly, but the edges are invisible.